# Python returns first and last item of a sequence exchanged

Tags: python, object-slicing

I need to create a function to slice a sequence in order that first and last item is exchanged and the middle stays in the middle. It needs to be able to handle string/list/tuples. I am having trouble with typeerrors - cant add list + int.

This:

```
def exchange_first_last(seq):
    """This returns the first and last item of a sequence exchanged"""
    first = seq[-1]
    mid = seq[1:-1]
    last = seq[0]
    return print(first+mid+last)
```

produces

(5, [2, 3, 4], 1)

But I don't want a list inside a tuple, just one flowing sequence.

(5,2,3,4,1,)

Any hints/suggestions welcome. The idea is to slice properly in order to handle different object types.

Comment: What is `seq` value? As I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Extract the fist and last elements as slices too; `first = seq[-1:]` and `last = seq[:1]`.  Then they'll have the same type as `seq`, and addition will work fine.

Comment: Why do you return the return value of `print`, which is `None`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def exchange_first_last(seq):
    """This returns the first and last item of a sequence exchanged"""
    first = seq[-1:]
    mid = seq[1:-1]
    last = seq[:1]
    return print(first+mid+last)
```

Comment: I just did this myself and it worked, came back here and saw what people said and here you are! Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code a little, notice the square brackets:

```
def exchange_first_last(seq):
    """This returns the first and last item of a sequence exchanged"""
    first = seq[-1]
    mid = seq[1:-1]
    last = seq[0]
    return print([first]+mid+[last])
```

Note it actually gives you a **list**, i.e. `[5,2,3,4,1]`, not a tuple `(5,2,3,4,1)`.

Comment: type(seq)([first]+mid+[last]) to make it a tuple when necesarry although I think a if is just much better

Answer (score 0):

You can use list.extend():

```
def exchange_first_last(seq):
    """This returns the first and last item of a sequence exchanged"""
    first = seq[-1]
    mid = seq[1:-1]
    last = seq[0]
    merged = []
    merged.extend(first)
    merged.extend(mid)
    merged.extend(last)
    return merged
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just swap the elements

```
def swap(l):
     temp = l[0]
     l[0] = l[-1]
     l[-1] = temp
     return l
```

Comment: This will not work with immutables like strings and tuples.

Comment: Didnt realize it was tuples